# How do i get the image path from another activity

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, drawable

what should i do to get the photopath of the captured image. so that i can display it in second activity as drawable?
First Activity

```
    btn_cam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            file = new File(MainActivity.this.getExternalCacheDir(),
                    String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
            fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        fileUri = data.getData();
            Intent cam = new Intent(this, MainCam.class);
            cam.putExtra("flostic", fileUri.toString());
            startActivity(cam);
            this.finish();
```

Second Acitivity

```
            String image_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("flostic");

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path, options);
            view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: use `setImageURI`, not `setImageBitmap`

Comment: how do i get the imagepath?

Comment: you dont - use `setImageURI` , not `setImageBitmap`

Comment: Did you, at least, read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/index.html)?

Comment: can you show me a sample code?@pskink

Comment: ok, you are not using `EXTRA_OUTPUT` so what file do you want to decode?

Comment: what do you mean file?the captured image?if so then yes.
sorry im just new in programming

Comment: are you using `android.provider.MediaStore#EXTRA_OUTPUT` ?

Comment: no. I only use the codes above

Comment: so if you are not using `EXTRA_OUTPUT` then what file do you want to decode? did your read `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` documentation?

Comment: @pskink. I update my codes

Comment: replace `cam.putExtra("flostic", fileUri.toString());` -> `cam.setData(fileUri);` and use that `Uri` directly in `setImageURI` method

Comment: can you show me the codes sample in second activity? I need help.

Comment: as i said: use `setImageURI(...)`, not `setImageBitmap(...)`

Comment: can you show me a complete solution?i need help. im really confused, i set uri by            
     Uri flostic = Uri.parse(extras.getString("flostic"));

Comment: i did. but how do i get to place that in SecondActivity

Comment: can you teach me here. since i dont have enough reputation to have a chat